# Get SQL Server temp table column type

Tags: sql-server, metadata, temp-tables

I'm loading CSVs into temporary tables like this:

```
select * 
into #Temp
from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                'Text;Database=D:\DataFolder;', 
                'SELECT * from [DataFile.csv]') as x;
```

The OLEDB driver determines a type for each column.

But temporary tables do not appear in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

How can I determine the data type for each column of the resulting `#Temp` table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how to get information for all the columns. Note that, in [tempdb], the table name is "____" with lots of underscores. So you have to access it as "LIKE __%", but this should work.

As a bonus, I added the code to get row counts.

As a note, I usually just "SELECT  INTO .." then script out the table and manually create the temp table. But the code below will work for what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
       [id]     INT
       , [name] NVARCHAR(12)
  );


--
-- get columns and types
------------------------------------------------- 
SELECT [columns].[name]
       , [types].[name]
       , [columns].*
       , [types].*
FROM   [tempdb].[sys].[columns] AS [columns]
       JOIN [tempdb].[sys].[tables] AS [tables]
         ON [tables].[object_id] = [columns].[object_id]
       JOIN [sys].[types] AS [types]
         ON [types].[user_type_id] = [columns].[user_type_id]
WHERE  [tables].[name] LIKE N'#test__%'; 


--
-- get row count
------------------------------------------------- 
SELECT [objects].[name]                      AS [table]
       , [dm_db_partition_stats].[row_count] AS [row_count]
       , *
FROM   [tempdb].[sys].[dm_db_partition_stats] AS [dm_db_partition_stats]
       INNER JOIN [tempdb].[sys].[objects] AS [objects]
               ON [dm_db_partition_stats].[object_id] = [objects].[object_id]
WHERE  [objects].[name] LIKE '#test%';
```

Comment: Very nice!  Now suppose I've been doing a lot of work in SSMS and I have multiple windows/connections open where I have defined temp tables like #test.  Is there an obvious way to scope it to the current window's instance?  (Or should I post this as a separate question?)

Comment: I've actually been meaning to write a presentation for my github repository and linkedin having to do with that issue. Try what you're suggesting and be surprised at the results. Further, create a local temp table in a parent procedure then try to access it in a child procedure, or overwrite it in the child. The results are not what you'd expect. But this is getting beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I threw what I have regarding local temp table (inheritance behavior) have out on github. If you're interested you should be able to use that to step through the scenario I mention. Note that I recommend NEVER using this side effect behavior, but you should be aware of it. https://github.com/KELightsey/chamomile/tree/master/presentation/temp_table_scoping

Comment: Wow, that's bewildering!  I wonder if the scoping of temp tables is "undefined," "indeterminate," or if it is deterministic and defined somewhere. 
 If you have an idea that would make a good self-answer question – I'll vote for it!

Comment: @feetwet, I'm not sure what I'd ask... I determined the behavior so I know what I'm seeing when I seem some OO junkie use it somewhere, but I have thought of creating a presentation that easily shows the behavior so others can spot and avoid it. I'll think about what might be an appropriate question. If you have something in mind though, go for it. my github site is a free for all. Use what you need.